# Receiving an Array to render in component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pass my state of thumbnail URLs that are saved to an array state. But when evaluating in my Netflix component videos is empty? When I console it, it returns `In tile {"videos":[]}`

**Render**

```
return (
  <div className="explore">
    <div className="row">
      <NetflixTile videos={this.state.thumbnail} />
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

**Constructor**

```
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.props.getVideos();
        this.state = {
          thumbnail: []
        };
      }
```

**DidMount EDITED**

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log("Component updated?");

    let i = 0;
    if (this.props.videos == null) {
      console.log("It's null");
    } else {
      const videos = this.props.videos.video.map(video => {
        <h5 key={video._id}>{video.thumbnail}</h5>;
        this.state.thumbnail[i] = video.thumbnail;
        console.log(this.state.thumbnail);
        i++;
      });
    }
  }
```

**Netflix component added into Render**

```
const NetflixTile = videos => {
  console.log("In tile " + JSON.stringify(videos.videos));
  if (videos.length != null) {
    for (let i = 0; videos > i; i++) {
      return (
        <div className="row__inner">
          <div className="tile">
            <div className="tile__media">
              <img
                className="tile__img"
                id="thumbnail"
                src={videos[i]}
                alt=""
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>
          You have not yet uploaded any STEM content. Go to your dashboard page
          and click Upload to add to this library.
        </h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default NetflixTile;
```

**Console output of `this.state.thumbnail` **
[image]

Comment: Are you fetching the data in `componentDidMount`? The data will not be loaded straight away, so `videos` will be an empty array on first render. You are also using `this.state.thumbnail` and `videos` instead of `videos.videos` in `NetflixTile`.

Comment: Not sure how you've got `this.state.thumbnails` fulfilled, since in your sample there is an empty initial state only. If this `getVideos` call is asynchronous (e.g. network) call then `componentDidMount` and `setState` should be used.

Comment: I added my componentDidMount code, my apologies for not doing that initially.

Comment: The second time through render my this.state.thumbnails gets filled. And that is consoled in that output above. I'm not sure why this is happening lol

Comment: @amankkg, your suggestion worked! Thank you!

Comment: @The_Enigma you're welcome. Updated my answer with improvements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, since you've got more or less working solution, let me update my answer with some suggestions then :)

1. Asynchronous calls (e.g. fetch) should be performed in `componentDidMount` (it is true until React's Suspense and async stuff is landed);
2. If you're not modifying videos' state of the parent component - use props directly, no need to bother with any state here at all.
3. In another case, keep in mind that `componentDidUpdate` will be called after each prop change or state change. Previously, I'd suggest using a `componentWillReceiveProps` for this kind of logic. But with React 16 you can use `getDerivedStateFromProps` instead. Here is what [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) are suggesting:

   > If you want to “reset” some state when a prop changes, consider either
   >   making a component fully controlled or fully uncontrolled with a key
   >   instead.

   As you can see, it is better to handle such comparison logic (e.g. `props.videos !== state.videos`) outside of component and make this component fully controlled, so it renders props directly and updates only when new props are received.
4. Try to minimize `setState` calls, however, you might not notice a big difference even with your current solution - it is because of React is batching state updates.
5. In JSX, it is better to use `Array.prototype.map` and ternary operators instead of `for` loops and `if` statements. Prefer working with value transformations rather than imperative statement jumping.

Applying these suggestions it can end up like this:

```
class VideosParentComponent extends React.Component {
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if (props.videos !== state.videos) {
      return { videos: props.videos }
    }

    return null
  }

  state = { videos: [] }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getVideos()
  }

  render() {
    const thumbnails = this.state.videos.video.map(video => video.thumbnail)
    return (
      <div className="explore">
        <div className="row">
          {thumbnails.length !== 0
            ? <NetflixTitle videos={thumbnails} />
            : (
              <div>
                <h1>
                  You have not yet uploaded any STEM content. Go to your dashboard page
                  click Upload to add to this library.
                </h1>
              </div>
            )}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const NetflixTitle = ({ videos }) => (
  <div className="row__inner">
    {videos.map(x => (
      <div key={x} className="tile">
        <div className="tile__media">
          <img
            id={`thumbnail_${x}`}
            src={x}
            className="tile__img"
            alt=""
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
)
```

---

### Initial answer

You're passing videos as a prop in JSX, not as a function parameter. This is why you should retrieve it as a **key in props** in a destination component.

```
const NetflixTitle = ({ videos }) => { // rest of the code
```

Comment: I tried this initially and it kept returning an empty array with not even "videos" showing inside it.

Comment: How did you get console output then?

Comment: `In tile []` just like this

Comment: Let me tinker with this, it's reading `this.state.videos.map(video => video.thumbnail);` as null.

Comment: @The_Enigma updated to match the shape of your `videos` prop. Naming is kinda confusing :)

Answer (score 0):

**Netflix Component Code**

```
const NetflixTile = ({ videos }) => {
      console.log("In tile " + JSON.stringify(videos));
      if (videos.length != 0) {
        for (let i = 0; videos > i; i++) {
          return (
            <div className="row__inner">
              <div className="tile">
                <div className="tile__media">
                  <img
                    className="tile__img"
                    id="thumbnail"
                    src={this.state.thumbnail[i]}
                    alt=""
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

**Rendered Component Code**

```
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.props.getVideos();
        this.state = {
          thumbnail: []
        };
      }
      componentDidUpdate() {
        console.log("Component updated?");

        let i = 0;
        if (this.props.videos == null) {
          console.log("It's null");
        } else {
          const videos = this.props.videos.video.map(video => {
            <h5 key={video._id}>{video.thumbnail}</h5>;
Added -->           this.setState({
      -->        thumbnail: video.thumbnail
            });
            //this.state.thumbnail[i] = video.thumbnail;
            console.log(this.state.thumbnail);
            i++;
          });
        }
      }

      render() {
        //return <div>{videos}</div>;
        return (
          <div className="explore">
            <div className="row">
              <NetflixTile videos={this.state.thumbnail} />
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```